# Calculate the area enclosed in $(x^2+y^2)^5=x^2y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the area of the plane contained within the curve
$$(x^2+y^2)^5=x^2y^2$$
Any suggepstion please?

Comment: Hint: use polar coordinates in double integral.

Comment: Alternative: Have you learned about [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: convert the expression into polar coordinates; $(r^2)^5 = r^{10} = r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta$.
It appears from the [wolfram alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E5%3Dx%5E2y%5E2) that the graph has adequate symmetry to just compute one "leaf". You can use either a double integral or the formula
$$A = \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{r^2}{2}\,d\theta$$
from there.

Comment: Thanks. In what way I can use the double integral? Can I have a sketch please?